# Fortigate and RADIUS Wifi authentication for domain and non-domain devices

Tags: wifi, radius, android, fortigate, fortinet

We're setting up RADIUS authentication for wireless network connections through a Windows Server 2012 R2 (NPS).

We have to allow both domain computers (registered in Active directory) and non-domain devices, typically Android smartphones.

Following this official [documentation](https://kb.fortinet.com/kb/documentLink.do?externalID=FD36088), the behaviour is as excepted and working fine for domain computers.

Now, we would like to set up mac address authentication for Android devices, also based on Active directory. Following several posts on this subject (like this [one](https://documentation.meraki.com/MR/Encryption_and_Authentication/Creating_User_Accounts_in_Active_Directory_for_MAC-based_Authentication)), we have created AD users with name and password being the mac address without colons or blank spaces (ie: bc4101d16900). We have then created another network policy within NPS configuration relative to the AD Security group containing the 'Android users'. This new policy differs from the computers policy in making reference to the 'Android users' Windows Group and not the computers Windows Group.

I'm eventually wondering if such a double authentication system is possible with a Fortigate firewall (mac-address for Android devices and computer name for domain PCs). I attach a picture showing both an overview of NPS configuration for Android devices and a smartphone screenshot when attempting to connect to the SSID.

[image]

Thanks for help or ideas!

Thomas Williamson